# c# Quickest way to compare elements in 2 lists and extract data on common element property?

Tags: c#, list

I have 2 lists of different objects (list A and list B) where both objects contain 1 common property (string X). I need to compare both lists and extract from each element in list A a certain property (string Y) where both properties in each list match on common (string X).

For example:

```
public class InventoryItem
{   
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public double Price { get; set; }
    public DateTime {get; set;}
    //more properties...
}

public class PurchaseItem
{   
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public double Price { get; set; }
    public DateTime {get; set;}
    //more properties...
}

List<InventoryItem>inventoryList;
List<PurchaseItem>purchaseList;
```

I need to loop through the "inventoryList" and set each element's "Price" in the "purchaseList" the same as the "inventoryList Price" where the "Description" is the same.

Answer (score 1):

This will do.

```
purchaseList.ForEach(i=> 
{
    var first = inventoryList.FirstOrDefault(p=>p.Description == i.Description);
    i.Price = first!=null? first.Price : i.Price;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can guarantee that there will always only be a maximum of one description in the inventoryList that matches the purchaseList, then this will do it. FirstOrDefault will return only the first matching item, or null if no matches are found.

```
foreach (InventoryItem item in inventoryList)
{
    PurchaseItem match = (from p in purchaseList
                          where p.Description == item.Description
                          select p).FirstOrDefault() as PurchaseItem;

    if (match != null)
    {
        match.Price = item.Price;
    }
}
```

If you wanted to change the price of all, regardless of how many, then another loop

```
foreach (InventoryItem item in inventoryList)
{
    List<PurchaseItem> matches = (from p in purchaseList
                                  where p.Description == item.Description
                                  select p).ToList();

    foreach (PurchaseItem match in matches)
    {
        match.Price = item.Price;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This Should do the trick

```
     List<Item> InventoryList = new List<Item>()
        {
            new Item { date = DateTime.Now, Description = "Orange", Price = 29.99 },
            new Item { date = DateTime.Now, Description = "Apple", Price = 99.99 },
            new Item { date = DateTime.Now, Description = "Grape", Price = 29.99 }
        };

        List<Item> PurchaseList = new List<Item>()
        {                
            new Item { date = DateTime.Now, Description = "Pear", Price = 29.99 },
            new Item { date = DateTime.Now, Description = "Orange", Price = 49.99 },
            new Item { date = DateTime.Now, Description = "Peach", Price = 29.99 }
        };

        foreach (var item in PurchaseList)
        {
            var match = InventoryList.Where(t => t.Description == item.Description).FirstOrDefault();
            if (match != null)
                item.Price = match.Price;
        }
```

And the class.

```
 public class Item
    {
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public double Price { get; set; }
        public DateTime date { get; set; }
    }
```